# Service Oriented Architecture - login system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, soa

I'm currently designing a Service oriented architecture, and actually I'm facing how to design the login system.

What actually I came out with is:

1. webUI (client that performs several operations on other services)
2. loginService (stores user credentials)
3. other services...

Since the WebUI is one of the way to access services it makes sense to me have the login to be a separated service, so also designing access to specific services can be easily implemented.

But I'm not really sure if this is a good approach to design a login system, that most of the times will be accessed by the web interface. It could also be integrated inside the webUI itself, exposing some way to authenticate users trying to access other services directly.... What do you think about this?

I hope that's clear what I'm trying to do, if not please ask me and I'll update this post with the info you need to better understand. Thanks.

Comment: Users and applications probably would not be happy to login and authorize every single time in every single service. Looks like you need a security service with [Single-Sing-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) facility on the board.

Comment: The scope of this question is huge, you need to under take background reading on SOA Governance and Federated Directory Services.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of related scenarios:

1. Actual users authenticate and the application subsequently calls web services on their behalf
2. A system calls the web services

For 1, you can provide a web login as you suggest.  You can then use the UsernameToken profile for web service authentication.  Alternatively, you can explore a SAML-based SSO solution depending on your requirements, and send a SAML token to the web service.

Look into an STS for the second.